# Difference between `normalize` and `parse` callbacks in redux-form

Tags: redux-form

The [current redux-form documentation](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Field.md) (version 6.5.0 at the time of this writing) mentions 2 callbacks for the `Field` object: `normalize` and `parse`.

Both descriptions sound pretty similar: They take the value entered by the user in an input field and transform it to a value stored in redux.

What's the difference between these 2 callbacks?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Essentially the two functions do exactly the same thing, i.e. take the `value` a user has input to the `Field` and transform it before it's stored in the redux store.

The differences lie in the [flavor](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Field.md/) of these functions and [the order in which they are called](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/ValueLifecycle.md/):

1. `parse` parses the string input value should convert it to the type you want to be stored the redux store, for example you parse a date string from a datepicker into a `Date` object
2. `normalize` is meant enforce certain formatting of input values in the redux store, [for example ensuring that phone numbers are stored in a cohesive format](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/normalizing/)

When it comes to the order in which these methods are called in the `redux-form` value lifecycle: `parse` is called before `normalize`, which means `normalize` is called with the parsed input value.

So in short, use `parse` to convert user input (usually in string form) to a type that suits your needs. Use `normalize` to enforce a specific input format on the user.

Answer (score 8):

This is what the [Value Lifecycle Hooks](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/ValueLifecycle.md/) page tries to explain.